# How to read result of bitwise operator OR (|)?

Tags: android, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

I would like the confirmation on bitwise operators inside Android XML files. For example this line

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
```

How should I read it? Are the rules inherited from Java or Android does its own interpretation of bitwise operators?

Are all bitwise operators supported? If yes, could you show me the example of other operators (link is fine as well)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `android_layout_gravity` is parsed by Android code. As documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_gravity), the only recognized operator here is `|`. I don't believe that interpreting `|` as bitwise OR operator is part of the spec. (For instance, `center_horizontal` is 0x05 and `right` is 0x01; their bitwise OR would just be 0x05.)

Comment: Center horizontal and right shouldn't be used together obviously. However you can use any bitwise operator you want, however it hase no goal, it's still 100% proper syntax. If you use center_horizontal and top 0x05|0x30 you'll get 0x35 and it's working as any other bitwise flag.

Comment: According to the link you sent me, this `|` is just a separator for multiple attributes. Right? Does it ever get treated as bitwise OR? I mean, both values are mandatory so the element will be position at the both locations.

Comment: @askmoo - I believe that the interpretation of the attribute value is indeed implemented as bitwise OR. But it could just as easily be implemented as a set of flags. As @piotrpo points out, logically incompatible values should not be used together; I believe the results are undefined if you do. (If the spec said that the values were combined using bitwise OR, then the results would be defined, but I can't find anywhere where this behavior is documented.) One could dig through the sources to see how it's implemented, but if it isn't defined, that could change in a future release.

Comment: Do you know if using of incompatible attributes will throw any error?

Answer (score 2):

```
2|1 = 3
2&1 = 0
3&1 = 1
```

central_horizontal, bottom are integers so you can use this construction

```
    int center_horizontal = 0x05; //just for clarification
    int other_orientation = 0x10;
    int orietntation = center_horizontal | other_orientation;

//this condition returns true
    if((orientation&center_horizontal)==center_horizontal){
        //something to do
        }
```

Comment: Hm, this is very interesting statement. When would you use such code? Why?

Comment: You can use it in creation of your own flags. You have asked, so i'll post answer. It's possible to use any of operators - &, |, ^ and it will work.