# What is the use of "|" in android's XML?

Tags: android, xml

android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"

what exactly is the function of the single bar here. Is it similar to the logical OR?

Comment: I think your question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457837/how-to-read-result-of-bitwise-operator-or topic.

Answer (score 2):

It indicates OR ... If you want to specify more than one condition, you need to use the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It means you take both options separated by the pipe. So it would be more a plus.